# Using Eclipse Microprofile NOT on root context (OpenLiberty)

Tags: open-liberty, microprofile

I'm using the eclipse microprofile (2.1) feature on my open liberty.
But all functions are running on root path (for example /health). 
I want to have it on an other context like "/app".

Is it to possible to do a configuration for that (maybe on server.xml)?
I couldn't find anything.

Not it is: localhost:8090/health
But i want: localhost:8090/app/health

Comment: currently there is no way to do this in OpenLiberty. However, can you elaborate a bit on the use case behind this? Then we might be able to come up with some alternatives/workarounds for you.

Comment: my application is running an docker and I have problems with the apache proxy and reverse proxy mapping. But I have to look whats the problem in detail to give you more hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With MicroProfile, the expectation is you're deploying a single application (microservice) per runtime and so it specifies that the endpoints are for the entire runtime.  Here's the extract from the latest spec, which now has two health endpoints:

"The MicroProfile Health Check architecture consists of two /health/ready and /health/live endpoints in a MicroProfile runtime that respectively represent the readiness and the liveness of the entire runtime."

Consequently, there's not way to control the endpoint.  If there's a use case that's broken, I'm sure the MicroProfile and/or Open Liberty communities would be open to changes.